# code only reads first line of text from source file

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was pretty sure my code was solid and should have taken in everything from my saved notepad but it appears it isn't. I thought it could also be that it may be taking everything into my array but not printing correctly. Could anyone point out where my mistake is? I'm at a loss.

This is the text from my .txt file:

> Jason 10 15 20 25 18 20 26
>   Samantha 15 18 29 16 26 20 23
>   Ravi 20 26 18 29 10 12 20
>   Sheila 17 20 15 26 18 25 12
>   Ankit 16 8 28 20 11 25 21

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void getData(ifstream& inf, string n[], double runData[][8], int count);
void calculateAverage(double runData[][8], int count);
void print(string n[], double runData[][8], int count);

int main()
{
    string names[5];
    double runData[6][8];

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("Lab15Runner.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the input file: Lab15Runner.txt." << endl;
        cout << "Program terminates!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    getData(inFile, names, runData, 5);
    calculateAverage(runData, 5);
    print(names, runData, 5);

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void getData(ifstream& inf, string n[], double runData[][8], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        inf >> n[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            inf >> runData[i][j];

        runData[i][8] = 0.0;

    }
}

void calculateAverage(double runData[][8], int count)
{
    double sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            sum = sum + runData[i][j];
        runData[i][8] = sum / 7;
    }
}

void print(string n[], double runData[][8], int count)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    cout << left << setw(10) << "Name"
        << right << setw(8) << "Day 1"
        << setw(8) << "Day 2"
        << setw(8) << "Day 3"
        << setw(8) << "Day 4"
        << setw(8) << "Day 5"
        << setw(8) << "Day 6"
        << setw(8) << "Day 7"
        << setw(10) << "Average" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(10) << n[i];
        cout << right;

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            cout << setw(8) << runData[i][j];
        cout << setw(8) << runData[i][9];

    }

}
```

Comment: `runData[i][8] = 0.0;` is writing out of bounds, and reading the 8th number (when `j == 7`) will fail because `Samantha` is not a number, which sets `failbit` and causes all future reads to also fail.

Comment: Looks like you're getting and index out of range, I'm surprised you're not getting a runtime error.  Dimensioned as [6][8], shouldn't the range in runData be [0-5][0-7]?

Comment: @Fhaab Why are you surprised?  Undefined behavior is undefined. There's no guarantee that it will crash.

Comment: @BenVoigt How is it writing out of bounds? I thought my matrix had 8 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 int values but you try to read 8 [0-7]. You are also trying to write in the position [8], when the last position in your array is [7].

```
n[i]         runData[i][j] --> [0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6] {Length = 7}  
  0   Jason                     10   15   20   25  18   20   26 
  1   Samantha                  15   18   29   16  26   20   23 
  2   Ravi                      20   26   18   29  10   12   20
  3   Sheila                    17   20   15   26  18   25   12 
  4   Ankit                     16    8   28   20  11   25   21
```

I changed your code and commented //CHANGED before the changes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void getData(ifstream& inf, string n[], double runData[][8], int count);
void calculateAverage(double runData[][8], int count);
void print(string n[], double runData[][8], int count);

int main()
{
    string names[5];
    double runData[6][8];

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("Lab15Runner.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the input file: Lab15Runner.txt." << endl;
        cout << "Program terminates!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    getData(inFile, names, runData, 5);
    calculateAverage(runData, 5);
    print(names, runData, 5);

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}

void getData(ifstream& inf, string n[], double runData[][8], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        inf >> n[i];

        //CHANGED - reads all 7 values after the name
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) // Old --> for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            inf >> runData[i][j];

        //CHANGED - set the last value (8th position) to 0.0
        runData[i][7] = 0.0; //Old --> runData[i][8] = 0.0;

    }
}

void calculateAverage(double runData[][8], int count)
{
    double sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        //CHANGED - sum all 7 values
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) //Old --> for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            sum = sum + runData[i][j];

        //CHANGED - update the 8th position
        runData[i][7] = sum / 7; // Old --> runData[i][8] = sum / 7;
    }
}

void print(string n[], double runData[][8], int count)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    cout << left << setw(10) << "Name"
        << right << setw(8) << "Day 1"
        << setw(8) << "Day 2"
        << setw(8) << "Day 3"
        << setw(8) << "Day 4"
        << setw(8) << "Day 5"
        << setw(8) << "Day 6"
        << setw(8) << "Day 7"
        << setw(10) << "Average" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(10) << n[i];
        cout << right;

        //CHANGED - Print all 7 values
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)// Old --> for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            cout << setw(8) << runData[i][j];

        //CHANGED - print the average (average is at position [i][7], position [i][9] doesn't exist) and added endl at the end
        cout << setw(8) << runData[i][7] << endl;// Old --> cout << setw(8) << runData[i][9];

    }

}
```

It should work fine like this.